# docker compose plugin is installed but when running it doesn't work

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine

when running docker compose version it show me the current version.

`$ docker compose version`

`Docker Compose version v2.12.2`

but when trying to use it

`$ sudo docker compose up`

docker: 'compose' is not a docker command.
See 'docker --help'

this is my docker version

$ sudo docker version

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           20.10.21
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.18.7
 Git commit:        baeda1f
 Built:             Tue Oct 25 18:02:21 2022
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.21
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.18.7
  Git commit:       3056208
  Built:            Tue Oct 25 18:00:04 2022
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.6.9
  GitCommit:        1c90a442489720eec95342e1789ee8a5e1b9536f
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.4
  GitCommit:        v1.1.4-0-g5fd4c4d
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

I expected `$ sudo docker compose up`
to run my .yml

Answer (score 0):

You may need to run the command as a super user.

try this: `sudo docker-compose up`

Comment: sudo: docker-compose: command not found

Comment: `$sudo docker-compose up`
sudo: docker-compose: command not found